The database transaction of the query is being rolled back, even though the query executed successfully using SQLAlchemy's async connection
After executing read-only queries using an asynchronous SQLAlchemy session with Python GraphQL-strawberry application, the database is still rolling back the associated transaction, even though the queries themselves were successful and the session has been closed.
For reference:
2024-10-28 09:59:37,983 api_name.py -> api_name() : 333 INFO: api_name retrieved successfully.
session closed sucessfully
2024-10-28 09:59:37,983 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
please can anyone help me with this.

If there are only read-only queries within the transaction, then it's irrelevant whether the transaction is closed by COMMIT or ROLLBACK. Are you observing an actual problem? If there is an actual problem, there is insufficient detail in the post to be able to replicate it.

Thank you for the response, No I am not facing any other issue. This was the one which I wanted to clarify
